# Visual Studio Code C# Ввод с клавиатуры

Tags: c#, input, клавиатура, visual-studio-code

Написал простенький код, который при вводе числа должен выдать на 10 больше.
компилирую, нажимая F5.
ввожу, допустим, число 50, вот в эту строку

получается вот что:

Прикрепляю код:

```
Console.WriteLine("Сейчас будем вводить...");
int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(x+10);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ndhC.png)

[image: компилирую, нажимая F5]

[image: ввожу, допустим, число 50, вот в эту строку]

[image: получается такая бадяга, не понимаю. мб я не туда ввожу или какую то платформу не подключил, хотя вроде все делал по инструкции]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не прикладывайте код картинками, прикладывайте текстом.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Сейчас будем вводить...");                                                                           int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                                                                                     Console.WriteLine(x+10);                                                                                                                Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Это нужно писать не в комментариях (тут код ещё сложнее читать, чем со скриншота, т.к. неудобны переводы строк), а нужно вписать в вопрос, нажав "править" под вопросом.

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что на консоли должно выводиться число на 10 больше, чем то, которое вводишь. Т.к. ничего подобного не выводится, я думаю, что либо я не туда ввожу либо что то не работает:(

Comment: В заголовке у вас Visual Studio, в метках Visual Studio Code - это разные программы.

Comment: исправил, спасибо

Comment: В LINQPad все нормально выполняется.

Comment: @AK, так он спрашивает, как значения вводить через vscode'ную консоль.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debug console используется только для вывода. Но с какой консолью будет работать ваше приложение можно поменять в настройках дебаггера (`launch.json`).

Нужно параметр `console` установить в значение `externalTerminal`.

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
       {
           "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
           "type": "coreclr",
           "request": "launch",
           "preLaunchTask": "build",
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ConsoleApp2.dll",
           "args": [],
           "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
           "stopAtEntry": false,
           "console": "externalTerminal"
       },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ,]
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, неделю маялся через блокнот записывать) а тут всего одна строчка. Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

```
    Console.WriteLine("Сейчас будем вводить...");
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(x+10);
    Console.ReadLine();
```